# Celery: Chaining subtasks

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have a main celery (in Django) task, which calls a subtask `prefetch`:

```
@shared_task
def main():
    ...
    tasks.prefetch.s().delay(x)
```

`Prefetch` itself calls some subtasks:

```
@shared_task
def prefetch(x):
    ...
    do_prefetch.s().delay(x)
```

In `main`, later down after `prefetch` is called I execute a number of other subtasks that do some processing. Those subtasks need to execute after `prefetch` has completed. `Prefetch` itself takes some time, so I want to not only execute `process` tasks after `prefetch`, but with a 60 second delay. `Process` tasks don't need the output of `prefetch`, they just need to run after it has completed. And `process` tasks can themselves be run in parallel to each other.

```
@shared_task
def main():
    ...
    tasks.prefetch.s().delay(x)
    ...
    for i in range(10):
        tasks.process.s().delay(i)
```

I see that Celery's canvas commands should get me what I need, but I don't know how to set up the tasks. Is the below correct? Do chains execute simply by creating them or do they need to be executed explicitly? Is my countdown argument in the right place and mean the right thing (execute this task any time 60 seconds after prefetch)?

```
prefetch = tasks.prefetch.s(x)
g = group(tasks.process.s(i, countdown=60) for i in range(10))
c = (prefetch | g)
c()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chord` instead of `chain` which fits best for your situation.

```
prefetch_task = tasks.prefetch.s(x)
group_task = group(tasks.process.s((i), countdown=60) for i in range(10))
work_flow = chord([prefetch_task])(group_task)
```

**[Chord](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html?highlight=group#celery.chord):**

A chord consists of a header and a body. The header is a group of tasks that MUST COMPLETE before the callback is called. A chord is essentially a callback for a group of tasks.

**Example:**

```
>>> from celery import chord
>>> res = chord([add.s(2, 2), add.s(4, 4)])(sum_task.s())
```

Here it will process both `add` tasks first and upon completion it will execute `sum_task`.

Comment: Chord [seems to require tasks that do not ignore results](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords). In our case there are no results.

Comment: So, what you are doing seems fine. If `prefetch` is not sending any values to `g`, then use immutable signatures. Use `tasks.process.si` instead of `tasks.process.s`

Comment: Would you still recommend chord or is chain OK?

Comment: Chain is ok in your case. Your have to use `group(tasks.process.s((i), countdown=60) for i in range(10))` so that celery knows which are `kwargs`; otherwise, it will ignore your `countdown`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about tasks.process.s(i).set(countdown=60) as in [the documentation bottom of this section](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#signatures)

Comment: Actually it should work, but it's not working as expected for me. May be i am doing something wrong. [Take a look](https://gist.github.com/ChillarAnand/77be59df924dd50ac9ce#file-gistfile1-txt)